# ERROR: Twisted-20.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, heroku, twisted

Python 3.8.3, Scrapy 2.2.0 and Twisted-20.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl are installed on my computer. Everything works as expected.
I can’t install Scrapy without Twisted, so Twisted is also installed, but when I try to transfer the application to Heroku, an error appears. How do I use Scrapy on Heroku?

````
-----> Found python-3.6.10, removing
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.8.3
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       ERROR: Twisted-20.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed```
````

Comment: It looks like it's trying to use the Windows version of the wheel and I'm thinking Heroku uses Linux. Maybe the requirements point to the non-Windows wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Twisted-20.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` in your `requirement.txt`

I don't think it's required because while installing `scrapy` it will be taken care of